# OpenGraph message preview messages are not showing in iMessage, but they're showing everywhere else

Tags: facebook-opengraph, imessage

We text customers a link to a webpage, and we want it to show up in the link preview. It's working on android, Facebook Messenger, and many other tools. It only shows in iMessage if sent from another iMessage. If it's from android or via Twilio API, it doesn't show a preview. Is there something I'm missing?

We 've tried debugging in Facebook's debugging tool, and it's all good. It works everywhere else. Is it a permissions/security issue?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue for myself. Turns out I just had an auth middleware from clerk that was blocking some routes. So Apple wasn't able to get the metadata. Not sure why facebook and other social networks were able to get it though.